# How can I call Cef.Shutdown from OnLoadingStateChanged()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'm forcing with Cef Sharp problem which I cannot resolve. My browser executes some code, then the function OnLoadingStateChanged checks for some condition. If condition is true then browser and all whole program should be end. The problem is that the browser instance run on thread (threadid 6) and my Cef.Initialize was call from thread (managedthreadid 1). How can I execute my method which close cef sharp on ManagedThreadID 1? Getting thread ID is possible in that case. Is it possible to call method on given thread when I know thread's id?

```
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Cef.Shutdown must be called on the same thread that Cef.Initialize was called - typically your UI thread. If you called Cef.Initialize on a Thread other than the UI thread then you will need to call Cef.Shutdown on the same thread. Cef.Initialize was called on ManagedThreadId: 1where Cef.Shutdown is being called on ManagedThreadId: 6
```

Thank You in advice ! :)

Comment: Are you using WinForms/WPF/OffScreen?

Comment: @amaitland I'm using Win Forms

Comment: Cef.Shutdown will be automatically called on application exit unless you've disabled it. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/84/CefSharp.WinForms/ChromiumWebBrowser.cs#L439 Please make sure you've read https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#initialize-and-shutdown

Comment: @amaitland But i have to end app immediately and automatically when condition in OnLoadingStateChanged is met. I'm reading those links and I still can't see the method which I should call when te condition is met : / There is only shutdown inside main function but main function is not running at the same thread as OnLoadingStateChanged where I need to close program

Comment: Close your form as you would normally.